# Ubuntu 14.04 update gcc 5.1.0 error

Tags: c++, c, linux, ubuntu, gcc

I'm studying linux now, so I have installed ubuntu 14.04(64bit),I want to update my gcc4.8.2 into gcc5.1.0,but it not work normally.
My step are as follows.

- First:

  - xtrat "gcc-5.1.0.tar.gz" into /usr/lib
  - Extrat "mpc-1.0.3.tar.gz" into /usr/lib/gcc-5.1.0/gcc_temp
  - Extrat "mpfr-3.1.2.tar.gz" into /usr/lib/gcc-5.1.0/gcc_temp
  - Extrat "gmp-6.0.0a.tar.bz2" into /usr/lib/gcc-5.1.0/gcc_tmp

- Second:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/lib/gcc-5.1.0/gcc_temp/gmp-6.0.0
make
make check
make install
```

```
cd /usr/lib/gcc-5.1.0/gcc_temp/mpfr-3.1.2
./configure --prefix=/usr/lib/gcc-5.1.0/gcc_temp/mpfr-3.1.2 --with-gmp=/usr/lib/gcc-5.1.0/gcc_temp/gmp-6.0.0
make
make check
make install
```

```
cd /usr/lib/gcc-5.1.0/gcc_temp/mpc-1.0.3
./configure --prefix=/usr/lib/gcc-5.1.0/gcc_temp/mpc-1.0.3 --with-gmp=/usr/lib/gcc-5.1.0/gcc_temp/gmp-6.0.0 --with-mpfr=/usr/lib/gcc-5.1.0/gcc_temp/mpfr-3.1.2
make
make check
make install
```

---

- Third:

```
cd /usr/lib/gcc-5.1.0
./configure --prefix=/usr/lib/gcc-5.1.0/gcc_temp --with-gmp=/usr/lib/gcc-5.1.0/gcc_temp/gmp-6.0.0 --with-mpc=/usr/lib/gcc-5.1.0/gcc_temp/mpc-1.0.3 --with-mpfr=/usr/lib/gcc-5.1.0/gcc_temp/mpfr-3.1.2 --enable-checking=release --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-multilib
make -j4
make install
```

- Finally

```
gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Now I don't know why failed, My gcc version is gcc4.8.2 still!

Comment: Please don't extract and compile anything into folders where you need root permissions. You should be doing this in your $HOME folder.

Comment: It's a bad idea to touch /usr/lib.

Comment: What instructions did you follow?

Comment: I recommend you follow these instructions here https://gcc.gnu.org/install/. Read them all carefully before you begin. In particular `--prefix` **should** point to where you want the compiler to be **installed** after it has been built.

Comment: I would recommend the following. Remove what you hace added to /usr/lib, reconfigure all components with `prefix=/usr/local` and reinstall. Your newest gcc should be in `/usr/local/bin`. You can *prepend* this directory to your PATH if you want. You probably should also *prepend* `/usr/local/lib` to your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, or alternatively add `-Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib` option to gcc when you compile.

Comment: If you want to link with libraries built against your system compiler's ABI then you will have to compile your programs setting this flag: `-D _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` The reason being the new compiler is not binary compatible with the old one unless you set that flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have taken your steps and changed them to something that looks a lot more sane.

Before doing this try to install the pre-requisite libraries using the package manager that comes with your Linux Distro.

```
Extract "mpc-1.0.3.tar.gz" into $HOME/dev/
cd $HOME/dev/mpc-1.0.3
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
sudo make install

Extract "mpfr-3.1.2.tar.gz" into $HOME/dev/
cd $HOME/dev/mpfr-3.1.2
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
sudo make install

Extract "gmp-6.0.0a.tar.bz2" into $HOME/dev/
cd $HOME/dev/gmp-6.0.0a
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
sudo make install

Extract "gcc-5.1.0.tar.gz" into $HOME/dev/
cd $HOME/dev/gcc-5.1.0
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --program-suffix=-5.1.0 --enable-threads=posix --disable-bootstrap --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-stage1-checking --disable-multilib
make
sudo make install
```

Please read through there instructions to fine tune your configuration: https://gcc.gnu.org/install/

Comment: But, How should I remove the old version of GCC now??

Comment: You don't need to remove the old version, just invoke the new one. Did you use the `--program-suffix` option from my example? If so you just need to use `g++-5.1.0` instead of just `g++` (assuming `/usr/local/bin` is in your `$PATH`).

Comment: @wengangli Try: `g++-5.1.0 --version` at the command line to check it works

Comment: "g++-5.1.0 --version" can't work, I create a link by "ln -s /usr/local/bin/gcc-5.1.0 /usr/bin/gcc",then it works....

Comment: `gcc` is the C compiler, you need `g++` for `c++`. You shouldn't really do it that way you should put `/usr/local/bin/ in your $PATH variable. I set mine in `$HOME/.bashrc`.